# Is this Symfony2 router configured correctly?

Tags: php, symfony, url-routing

I have been asked to fix a broken contact form on a client's site. The `emailsend` action is supposed to be fired when the form is submitted but it doesn't seem to work. I have examined the router and it seems to me that there are two routes for `/contact`, meaning that this action will never be fired because the requirements are already met by the other route with that path. Is my understanding of this correct? If so then I don't get why the contact form was supposedly working before!

```
foo_core_homepage:
    path:     /
    defaults: { _controller: FooCoreBundle:Default:index }

foo_core_ourwork:
    path:     /work
    defaults: { _controller: FooCoreBundle:Default:clients }

foo_core_services:
    path:     /services
    defaults: { _controller: FooCoreBundle:Default:services }
​
foo_core_contact:
    path:     /contact
    defaults: { _controller: FooCoreBundle:Default:contactMobile }
​
foo_core_findus:
        path:     /findus
        defaults: { _controller: FooCoreBundle:Default:findus }

foo_core_email_send:
    path:   /contact
    defaults: { _controller: FooCoreBundle:Default:emailsend }
```

Comment: Routes are evaluated in definition order. When a match is found, it stops the search, picks that route and runs it. You need to define your routes from most strict to least strict to avoid these kind of issues.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't write this router, in fact I haven't used Symfony much before. Am I correct that the last route won't ever be matched?

Comment: yes `foo_core_email_send` will never be called

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, one of the two routes using the same path will not be available.
You can check which of them using the `debug:router` command, but it will surely be the last.

The way to differenciate them is to define different requirements like follows:

```
foo_core_contact:
    path:     /contact
    defaults: { _controller: FooCoreBundle:Default:contactMobile }
    requirements:
        methods: GET​

foo_core_email_send:
    path:   /contact
    defaults: { _controller: FooCoreBundle:Default:emailsend }
    requirements:
        methods: POST
```

**Note** : I don't know how your form is displayed, same for how it is handled, so you are not free of other problems about calling or not the good route(s) on submit.

Comment: Thanks, I will do that. I'm not sure how this was supposedly working originally! Maybe they just didn't notice that they weren't getting any emails. :/

Comment: You're welcome ! Don't hesitate to ask another question if the problem persists, I'll be glad to help you to debug it.